# Extracting data from table with results from different search

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to extract data from tables with the results from a previous search. I am not really familiar with database query's and have made one that will crash my computer from drawing too much memory.

This data is coming from a board tester and I want certain information.

1. How many boards were ran during a given period
2. How many failed
3. All the failure data for those boards **EDIT:** This is the one I need to figure out. See Edit at bottom.

The first time a board is ran it creates a record in the Board table

```
+----------+-------+-----+
| Board_id | Board | rev |
+----------+-------+-----+
|        1 | 1234  | 1   |
|        2 | 1234  | 1   |
|        3 | 1235  | 2   |
|        4 | 5869  | 15  |
+----------+-------+-----+
```

Each time the board is ran it creates a Test record

```
+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+
| Test_id  | Board_id | Operator| Date_Time           |
+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+
|       34 | 1        | 1       | 2017-08-02 09:13:34 |
|       35 | 1        | 1       | 2017-08-02 09:13:36 |
|       36 | 1        | 1       | 2017-08-02 09:13:39 |
|       37 | 2        | 1       | 2017-08-02 09:14:10 |
|       38 | 3        | 1       | 2017-08-02 09:16:24 |
|       39 | 3        | 2       | 2017-08-03 10:40:45 |
|       40 | 4        | 2       | 2017-08-03 10:43:34 |
+----------+----------+---------+---------------------+
```

...and Results are stored in Results

```
+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+-------------+
| Result_id | Test_id | Result | Upper_Limit | Lower_Limit |
+-----------+---------+----------------------+-------------+
|       40  | 34      | 2      | 4           | 1           |
|       41  | 34      | 3      | 4           | 1           |
|       42  | 34      | 4      | 4           | 1           |
|       43  | 34      | 0      | 4           | 1           |
|       44  | 35      | 2      | 4           | 1           |
|       45  | 35      | 3      | 4           | 1           |
|       46  | 35      | 4      | 4           | 1           |
|       47  | 35      | 0      | 4           | 1           |
|       48  | 36      | 2      | 4           | 1           |
|       49  | 36      | 3      | 4           | 1           |
|       50  | 36      | 4      | 4           | 1           |
|       51  | 36      | 2      | 4           | 1           |
|       52  | 37      | 2      | 4           | 1           |
|       53  | 37      | 3      | 4           | 1           |
|       54  | 37      | 4      | 4           | 1           |
|       55  | 37      | 2      | 4           | 1           |
|       56  | 38      | 2      | 4           | 1           |
|       57  | 38      | 3      | 4           | 1           |
|       58  | 38      | 4      | 4           | 1           |
|       59  | 38      | 5      | 4           | 1           |
|       60  | 39      | 2      | 4           | 1           |
|       61  | 39      | 3      | 4           | 1           |
|       62  | 39      | 4      | 4           | 1           |
|       63  | 39      | 5      | 4           | 1           |
|       64  | 40      | 2      | 4           | 1           |
|       65  | 40      | 3      | 4           | 1           |
|       66  | 40      | 4      | 4           | 1           |
|       67  | 40      | 3      | 4           | 1           |
+-----------+---------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

To get the number of boards, and Board_ID, ran during a given period I query.

```
SELECT a.Board_ID  FROM    
    Tests a, Results b
WHERE a.Date_Time>='2017-08-02' AND a.Date_Time<'2017-08-03' and
    a.Test_ID = b.Test_ID
    group by a.Board_ID
```

To get all associated test to those Board_ID's I query.

```
SELECT *  from 
    Tests x, (
    SELECT a.Board_ID  FROM    
        Tests a, Results b
    WHERE a.Date_Time>='2017-08-02' AND a.Date_Time<'2017-08-03' and
        a.Test_ID = b.Test_ID
        group by a.Board_ID
    ) y
where x.Board_ID = y.Board_ID
```

This gives me the correct results, but the query seems off, but when I try to get the failed results from the query above is when I have the most trouble.

```
SELECT d.Test_ID  FROM 
    Boards a, Tests b, (
    SELECT x.Test_ID, x.Board_ID, x.Operator, x.Date_Time  from 
        Tests x, (
        SELECT a.Board_ID  FROM    
            Tests a, Results b
        WHERE a.Date_Time>='2017-08-02' AND a.Date_Time<'2017-08-03' and
              a.Test_ID = b.Test_ID
              group by a.Board_ID
         ) y
    )d
WHERE d.Test_ID = b.Test_ID and
    b.Result not between Lower_Limit and Upper_Limit
```

**EDIT:**

If you look at the Test table I created you will see that board_id 3 got tested twice and on two different days. I need to see the boards that we ran on a given day, this example 2017-08-02, and all associated records to those boards. So since Board_ID #3 was ran on 2 days, and was ran on the day in question, I would need that record included in my query.

**My Solution**

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT x.Test_ID, x.Board_ID, x.Operator, x.Date_Time  from 
        Test x, (
            SELECT a.Board_ID  FROM    
                Test a
                join Results b on a.Test_ID = b.Test_ID
            WHERE a.Date_Time>='2017-08-11' AND a.Date_Time<'2017-08-12' 
                group by a.Board_ID
        ) y
    where x.Board_ID = y.Board_ID
)d
    join Boards a on a.Board_ID = d.Board_ID
    join Results b on b.Test_ID = d.Test_ID
    join Test_Names c on c.Test_Name_ID = b.Test_Name_ID --Table Not shown
WHERE
    b.result not between Lower_Limit and Upper_Limit
```

From this you see I have 3 nested searches into 1. With the 3 individual searches I get all the data I need to parse the information I want. Next will be to find a way to query the database for what I need instead of parsing.

Comment: Please check that you pasted the last query correctly.  It abruptly ends with "and" and I also see "d.Test_ID = d.Test_ID", which I assure you will always be true :)

Comment: You should also look into using `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Comma separating tables was popular 20-30 years ago and will stop working at some point (hopefully)

Comment: You don't actually count anything. So why the aggregate? And why subqueries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overthinking this.  You don't need all the inline views.  Here's how I would write it using ANSI Joins (like @CptMisery suggested in the comments)

```
SELECT d.test_id, b.board, b.board_rev, r.result_id, r.result -- and whatever else you need.  
from tests t
join results r on t.test_id = r.test_id
join boards b on t.board_id = b.board_id
where t.Date_Time>='2017-08-02' AND t.Date_Time<'2017-08-03'
and r.result >Lower_Limit -- or >=
and r.result < Upper_Limit -- or <=, if it can be the limit value
```

JOIN all the tables based on their relationships (Foreign Key to Primary Key), choose your filters in the where clause, and choose the columns to "project" with Select.

Comment: Kevin, this almost got me exactly what I am looking for. If you look at the Test table I created you will see that board_id 3 got tested twice and on two different days. I need to see the boards that we ran on a given day and all associated records to those boards. Ideas?

Comment: I missed the "All associated tests" detail.  The query will be a mix of my answer, and your original attempt.  I'll try to edit later.

Comment: Used a combination of the join and the nested search to get the data I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.Test_ID  FROM 
    Boards a, Tests b, ( SELECT x.Test_ID, 
                                x.Board_ID, 
                                x.Operator, 
                                x.Date_Time  
                           from  Tests x, 
                                 (SELECT a.Board_ID  
                                    FROM Tests a, Results b
                                   WHERE a.Date_Time>='2017-08-02' 
                                     AND a.Date_Time<'2017-08-03' 
                                     and  a.Test_ID = b.Test_ID
                                group by a.Board_ID
                                   ) y
                          )d
  WHERE d.Test_ID = d.Test_ID 
    and b.Result >= Lower_Limit
    and b. Result <=Upper_Limit
```

Comment: Just check if datatype of both the columns is same and replace  d.Test_ID = d.Test_ID  with  d.Test_ID = b. Test_ID          The correct code will be SELECT d.Test_ID FROM Boards a, Tests b, ( SELECT x.Test_ID, x.Board_ID, x.Operator, x.Date_Time from Tests x, ( SELECT a.Board_ID FROM
Tests a, Results b WHERE a.Date_Time>='2017-08-02' AND a.Date_Time<'2017-08-03' and a.Test_ID = b.Test_ID group by a.Board_ID ) y )d WHERE b.Test_ID = d.Test_ID and b.Result >= Lower_Limit and b. Result <=Upper_Limit